# How to see all latex options?

Tags: org-mode, latex

Somewhere I've *heard* that having `draft` somewhere in LaTex doesn't print pictures. Given being in my org file and having no internet connection, how can I use that very vague knowledge to learn about using it in org mode? Tried various `C-h` commands with no results on the term `draft`

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).  Your local TeX distribution almost surely includes documentation, e.g., you can run `$ texdoc graphicx` in a terminal to see the documentation of the `graphicx` package where its `draft` option is explained.

Comment: If you have AUCTeX, you can also use `M-x TeX-doc`.

Comment: @d125q I'd still would need to know how to use in the context of `org-mode`

Comment: Is this a "desert island" question? Obviously, you have an internet connection in order to post the question on SE. So are you asking: how would I go about finding something if I had a laptop on a desert island with no possibility to add anything to my laptop? If so, the answer is: it depends on whether that information is already on your laptop. In general, you won't be able to answer any specific question (including the specific one you are asking). The Emacs Info system is not an all-knowing genie: it depends on whether you have installed the appropriate Info file (if one even exists).

Comment: @NickD Yes "desert island" pretty much nails it. Metaphorically.  I'll investigate further on the usage of the Emacs info system. Thank you.